# How to remove text from value using SUBSTR in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a domain that looks like so:

```
www.google.com
```

I would like to remove 'www' from that and output would be as follows in a new field:

````
google.com
```

Current query is as follows but does not seem to work:
```
SELECT 
contact.ID,
contact.ACCOUNT_ID,
contact.NAME,
contact.EMAIL,
SUBSTR(contact.EMAIL,CHARINDEX('www',contact.EMAIL)+1,LEN(contact.EMAIL)) as Domain
FROM
contact
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use `REPLACE` :

```
SELECT 
  contact.ID,
  contact.ACCOUNT_ID,
  contact.NAME,
  contact.EMAIL,
  REPLACE(contact.EMAIL , 'www.')
FROM
contact
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use regexp_replace, this will replace the 1st occurrence or wwww (depending upon your requirement)

```
select regexp_replace('www.google.com', 'www.','',1,1) as "result" from dual UNION
select regexp_replace('www.googleWWW.com', 'www.','',1,1) as "result" from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this more foolproof.

```
 set str='www.google.com';
 select case when $str ilike 'www.%' then right($str,len($str)-4) else $str end;
```